# How exactly to use screen in linux / SSH shell?

Tags: linux, ssh, gnu-screen

I read the manual and online help, but still cannot grasp the idea of the screen command.
Lets say I SSH to my linux shell. Inside it I want to run a program that will run for 8 hours:

1. I create a "detached screen" by entering `screen` and then `crtl+a`, `crtl+d` to deattach it.
2. Then I run my program `my_prog`

What to do then? How do I return back to my normal terminal and continue my normal session started with?
If I just close the SSH window and reconnect, then my program stops.

My question is that exact steps I must make to:

1. Work in the shell as normal
2. Run screen to run a program in the background
3. Continue working in the old shell
4. Exit the SSH session
5. Establish a new SSH session and switch to my program that has worked while I was gone

Or is it the other way around? I enter  `my_prog &`, then call `screen` and detach and then close the terminal window?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

1. You start `screen`,
2. Run the program *in* `screen`,
3. And *then* detach it.
4. `screen -R` to attach it again.

If you run many independent `screen` sessions, then use the `-S` option to name your sessions and to attach named sessions, or use `-ls` to list existing sessions, and attach to those.

Comment: Thanks, now I get it. I thought it was the other way around, that screen makes a detached session.